# Changing the ID for an element doesn't work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the ID of an element (a `<div>`) using jQuery. Below is an example of my JavaScript, CSS and HTML. Right now, when I click the `<div>`, nothing happens.

```js
$( ".pre_div" ).click(function() { 
  $( ".pre_div" ).attr('id','after_div');
});
$( ".after_div" ).click(function() { 
  $( ".after_div" ).attr('id','pre_div');
});
```

```css
#pre_div {width:20px;height:20px;background-color:red;cursor:pointer;}
#after_div{width:20px;height:20px;background-color:blue;cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<div id="pre_div">:-)</div>
```

Comment: Sorry...didnt get your question..could you please explain it clearly.

Comment: Rephrased title and question to make it more clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is for classes and `#` is for ids, plus you have to use the `.on()` function, otherwise it will not work

```
$(document).on('click','#pre_div',function() { 
  $(this).attr('id','after_div');
});

$(document).on('click','#after_div',function() { 
  $(this).attr('id','pre_div');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/19dh4ouf/)

Comment: thanks, but the second click on the div is not working. The Div should be red again.

Comment: It would be interesting to explain _why_ this works, not just that it works. (and I'm talking specifically about using the "on" function as opposed to attaching the event to the div.

Comment: This is using event delegation on the `document`: every time the `document` is clicked and a `#pre_div` is in the DOM tree to the node that caused the click the event will fire. [See the jQuery.on docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `#` – id selector – instead of `.` – class selector (also, you can use `this` to access element within it's event listener):

```
$( "#pre_div" ).click(function() { 
  $(this).attr('id','after_div');
});
$( "#after_div" ).click(function() { 
  $(this).attr('id','pre_div');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rcqr5f32/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use `$(this)` to refer to the clicked item otherwise you may give many item the same `id`. However, with this approach, you are still assiging the same id to each clicked div, which is not good. How about adding the `index` of the clicked `div` to make it a **unique** `id`:

```
$(".pre_div").click(function() { //any div with pre_div class
  $(this).attr('id'+ $(this).index(),'after_div');
});
$(".after_div").click(function() { //any div with after_div class
  $(this).attr('id'+ $(this).index(),'pre_div');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"pre_div" and "after_div" are not classes, they are id's of your div

Should access it like this way.

```
$( "#pre_div" ).click(function() { 
  $( "#pre_div" ).attr('id','after_div');
});
$( "#after_div" ).click(function() { 
  $( "#after_div" ).attr('id','pre_div');
});
```